# Formula for time calculation within one cell

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-excel

I want to put in a formula that calculates the difference between two times within the same cell.

For example the shift 6-2 or 6am-2pm equals 8 hours, and have the total sum of the shifts for two weeks at the end in column "p"

Comment: Keep in mind "6-2" could be 20 hours as well.  Probably best to split the shift start and end times into different columns, since they are different data points that you want to work with.

Comment: There is no easy solution to just enter a formula for what you ask. Assuming you are working in Excel, it would see `6-2` as a date (or text) and not run a calculation on it properly. I agree with @techie007, you should split out the start and stop times to be able to perform the proper calculations.

Answer (score 2):

This is a surprisingly complicated problem due to the way Excel stores and manages dates. This solution makes a number of assumptions, specifically:

- times specified do not span more than 24 hours
- am and pm are specified in both start and end dates
- there are no extraneous characters in the shift field
- each day's entry must be calculated independently (no two-week total in one cell)

Take the following example data:

[image: Shift Time Breakdown Example]

Cell **B2** holds the following formula:

```
=TIME(LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-3)
      +IF(MID(A2,FIND("-",A2)-2,2)="pm",12,0),0,0)
```

Cell **C2** holds the following formula:

```
=TIME(MID(A2,FIND("-",A2)+1,LEN(A2)-FIND("-",A2)-2)
      +IF(RIGHT(A2,2)="pm",12,0),0,0)
```

Cell **D2** holds the following formula:

```
=IF(C2>B2,C2-B2,C2+1-B2)*24
```

These cells could theoretically be combined, replacing every reference to **B2** and **C2** in the final formula with the actual **TIME** function from each cell.

If the ultimate objective is to sum a series of shifts for a two-week total, I recommend adding an additional row (or column) of calculations for each day individually. The row can be referenced to sum the hours and the row can be hidden from view to keep from disrupting the flow of the document.